# after custom order->save() not returning and stopping execution in magento

Tags: magento, edi

after custom order->save() not returning and stopping execution in magento

my code below: ​​

```
$order->setPartnerWarehouse($wareHouse);
$order->setTradingPartner($businessType);
$order->setPartnerOrderId($partnerOrderId);
$order->setWarehouse($wareHouse); 
$order->setCustomerOrderNumber($customerOrderNumber);
$order->setPickupDate($pickup->datetime);
$order->setPickupMethod($pickup->description);
$order->setPartnerShipmentMethod($pickup->code);
$order->save();
$icn = rand(100000000, 999999999);
$edi = generateResponse_855($order, $icn);
echo $edi;
```

i am not able to return anything after order save action, is there any thing, please suggest

Comment: try {
              $order->save();             
             } 
                  catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                  $this->_fault('data_invalid', $e->getMessage());
                 }

Comment: still not coming, its not falling into catch, it is creating order but not returning anything

Comment: Then maybe generateResponse_855 fails. Can you show us the code from that function?

Comment: i tried that as well with any function, after order save not returned any values, this may be because of any value is not set?